# Proving the restriction map is continuous surjective

Tags: functional-analysis, continuity, operator-theory, normed-spaces

Let $X$ be a normed vector space and $Y$ be a subspace of $X$. Define $\phi: X^* \rightarrow Y^*$ defined by $\phi(f)=f_{|_Y}$, where $X^*$ represents the collection of all continuous linear functionals $f:X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

We want to show that $\phi$ is linear continuous surjective. I was able to show the linearity and the onto, but not sure how to start the proof of the continuity, should I prove the boundedness of the operator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have
$$\||\phi ||_{X^* \to Y^*} =\sup_{f\in X^* , ||f||_{X^* }=1  }||\phi (f) ||_{Y^*}=\sup_{f\in X^* , ||f||_{X^* }=1  }\sup_{y\in Y, ||y||=1}|f|_Y (y)|\leq \sup_{f\in X^* , ||f||_{X^* }=1  }\sup_{x\in X, ||x||=1}|f(x)|=\sup_{f\in X^* , ||f||_{X^* }=1  }||f||_{X^*} =1$$
thus $\phi$ is continous.